# LibreOffice Basic get Elements from form

Tags: forms, libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-base, libreoffice-basic

I'm trying to get value from textfield on the form.

```
sub Test(oEv)

oForm = oEv.Source.Model.Parent
textBox = oForm.getByName("Description")
MsgBox textBox.Text

end sub
```

There is an Exception: "Type: com.sun.star.container.NoSuchElementException" on the line "textBox = oForm.getByName". I have a text field with the name "Description" on the same form, where is the button I press to run this macro. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the name is the same case, not `description`.

Also, use the [Form Navigator](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Form_Navigator) to determine whether the control is under the form in the hierarchy.

Have you tried using an introspection tool such as [MRI](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/mri-uno-object-inspection-tool) or [XrayTool](http://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html) to view the properties of `oForm`?  With the tool, expand the form to see if it contains the `Description` control.

Often in Base, it is better to deal with the form as a recordset rather than reading the controls.  Here is some sample code:

```vb
Sub ButtonClickHandler(oEvent as Object)
    'com.sun.star.comp.forms.ODatabaseForm
    oForm = oEvent.Source.Model.Parent
    lDescriptionCol = oForm.findColumn("DESCRIPTION")  ' from underlying query or table
    Print(oForm.getString(lDescriptionCol))
    BasicLibraries.LoadLibrary("XrayTool")
    xray(oForm)
End Sub
```

For more ideas, see https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=38725.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried MRI, but it couldn't help me to find solution. Then I tried to restart LibreOffice - and everything worked! Don't know what caused this problem.